# Apache server Website should point to Vhost but is searching in html folder on upgrade

Tags: apache-2.2, php, web-server

I upgraded my server from 2.2 to 2.2.22 . When I open my website in chrome it says successfully installed and

```
You may now add content to the directory /var/www/html/. Note that until you do so, people visiting your website will see this page and not your content. To prevent this page from ever being used, follow the instructions in the file /etc/httpd/conf.d/welcome.conf.
```

But earlier the 2 site which were hosted on the server were at

```
/var/www/vhosts/sitename/httpdocs/httpdocs
```

During the upgrade i encountered an error

> error: unpacking of archive failed on file /usr/lib64/apr-1/build:
>   cpio: rename failed - Is a directory Execute command touch
>   /var/lock/parallels-panel-upgrade-failure.flag ; rm -f
>   /var/lock/parallels-panel-maintenance-mode.flag Execute command
>   /usr/local/psa/admin/bin/send-error-report install Execute command
>   /usr/sbin/getenforce Disabled Error: An error occurred during
>   installation of packages. Attention! Your software might be
>   inoperable. Please, contact product technical support.

How can i run the website now ?

Answer (score 0):

Try maybe moving the stuff from /var/www/vhosts/sitename/httpdocs/httpdocs to /var/www/html and see what happens ?

Comment: The Folder is very heavy , is there some way where i can point the Porper location ? to Vhost ?

Comment: Use a symlink `ln -s /var/www/html /var/www/vhosts/sitename/httpdocs/httpdocs`